# MATLAB slowing down with many instances of script running

Tags: matlab

some users (right now 4) are running the same rather large and heavy MATLAB (R2010b) script on the same windows server.

There seems to be a rather big drop in performance in the MATLAB (observed a factor 5 in running time when doing a bit of benchmarking) when more users are running the same script on the server (many different datasets). Depending on the size of the dataset the running time is between a few hours and 1-2 weeks.

There is plenty of CPU and RAM resources available on the server, this is not the bottleneck. This server has 64 cores and 128 GB RAM, the program uses no more than 10% of the CPU, most of the time less than, and about 1 GB of RAM while running).

It does not seem to be a bottleneck related to hardware, as the server in general is running other programs without any significant slow down, only MATLAB seems to be slowing down.

Is there some kind of internal resources in MATLAB that is being used up and creating a bottleneck and if so is there a way to get around this?

*Edit, extra info*

When running "bench" while the scripts are running I also get extremely slow speed from this internal machine benchmarking, worse for the heavier tests ... this indicates to me it is not directly related to reading/writing files, it might be indirectly related if matlab writes some temporary files.

Also just tried to increase Java Heap Memory to 10 GB ... it does improve performance a bit, but there is still a very clear slowdown with each new instance of this script that is being run.

Update: upgrading to MATLAB 2015B didn't change much. We have improved a lot on the code so it runs much faster now, but the issue still remains even though the problem is smaller since the program is script is running for shorter amounts of time for each user.

Comment: Can hard disk be the bottleneck? Does the script read or save files?

Comment: It is possible ... inside the script it is writing a file every 1 minute and it takes a few seconds, so this should not be problem... but maybe something with temporary files that matlab writes. The script does read rather big files (a few MB) ... but it does not seem to be where the code is spending most of it's time

Comment: Try to use `profile` and compare the results for two runs processing identical data. If you don't understand the results use `profsave` to generate a HTML report and upload them somewhere. How are the four scripts started? Four separate Matlab instances or any use of the distributed computing features?

Comment: If you use big matrices, it is possible that you adverse effects of exceeding your 3rd level cache size. What is the innermost operation?

Comment: @Alexander It sounds very likely that some cache is the problem, we have seen this problem in different ways where any matlab session on the same server just slows down when running different kinds of heavy scripts on other sessions of Matlab running. One example of the core of the scrips something like this`y(I,J)=((-1)^n*(x(I,J)/Tau)^(n*C))/gamma(1+n*C);
            while n*C*log(x(I,J)/Tau)-gammaln(1+n*C)>accuracy
                n=n+1;
                y(I,J)=y(I,J)+(-1)^n*exp(n*C*log(x(I,J)/Tau)-gammaln(1+n*C));
            end
            y(I,J)=y(I,J)*M0;`

Comment: but there are in general big matrices going on in the different scripts outside of this little core of code showed above. There is a lot of linear fitting, with some harmonic denoising of signal going on as well for example as well.